# wampserver load php_pgsql.dll error

Tags: php

wampserver load `php_pgsql.dll` error :

> **PHP Warning:**  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_pgsql.dll' -
>   \xb2\xd9\xd7\xf7\xcf\xb5\xcd\xb3\xce\xde\xb7\xa8\xd4\xcb\xd0\xd0
>   %1\xa1\xa3\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the `libpq.dll` from your PHP directory to the Apache bin directory.

If it do not work out for you, you have to load `libpq.dll` in the `httpd.conf` like below

```
LoadFile "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/libpq.dll"
```

Comment: Thank you!It has been solved.The apache configuration file added a character caused by the mistake.sorry,I am an Chinese PHPer.My English is very poor。